# Query model data with relationship count and performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have problems with query performance with Postgresql and Rails counting related models while retrieving data.

```rb
class MasterModel
  # few fields, like name, description and such

  has_and_belongs_to_many :business_models, class: 'BusinessModel'
end
```

```rb
class BusinessModel
  # Lots of important information, many fields

  has_and_belongs_to_many :master_models, class: 'MasterModel'
end
```

The use case in question being that `business_model` can be related to any amount of `master_model` so typically you should have a small amount of `master_model`, a great amount of `business_model` and a even bigger amount of many to many relationships.

When showing `master_model` index page, you can visualize its information and a `delete` button only enabled when there are no relationships, hence the reason why its important to count the relationship in its representation.

So I tried some ways to achieve this:

1. Includes relationship is incredibly slow in ActiveRecord but not in query time. At least it has no N+1.

```rb
MasterModel.includes(:business_models).limit(50).offset(0).each do |master|
  master.business_models.size
end
```

2. No includes. We have N+1 but is incredibly fast as long as model pagination is reasonable.

```rb
MasterModel.limit(50).offset(0).each do |master|
  master.business_models.size
end
```

3. Given that I only need to know if relationships exists or not I tried a select with exists. Single query and fast.

```rb
MasterModel.select(
  :id,
  :name,
  :description.
  'NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT many.master_id
    FROM many
    WHERE many.master_id = master.id
  ) AS removable'
).limit(50).offset(0).each do |master|
  master.business_models.removable
end
```

In the end, I chose the 3rd choice but I am not totally convinced. What would be the Rails way? Am I doing something wrong in the other cases?

Comment: First of all, I'd avoid `all.each` - it loads everything in memory, so your app could easily die even if there is no problem with the request performance per se, just because of the number of entries in the table. `Model.find_each { ... }` iterates over the dataset in batches and therefore it is much-much safer and predictable. This might be the main reason for your solution nr. 1 to be incredibly slow on the ORM layer.

Comment: I wrote `all.each` for simplicity, we are paginating the request so that we are loading less than 100 elements at most. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would used `has_many through` association you would be able to use `counter_cache` but HABTM doesn't support `counter_cache` so that you can implement your own `counter_cache`

First of all you need to add new integer column to the `master_models` table called `business_models_count`

```rb
add_column :master_models, :business_models_count, :integer, default: 0
```

And add next code to your model `MasterModel`

```rb
class MasterModel
  has_and_belongs_to_many :business_models, class: 'BusinessModel', before_add: :inc_business_models_count, before_remove: :dec_business_models_count

  private

  def inc_business_models_count(*)
    self.increment!(:business_models_count)
  end

  def dec_business_models_count(*)
    self.decrement!(:business_models_count)
  end
end
```

And write some rake task which goes through `MasterModel` records and update counter for existing records.

It can be done like this:

```rb
MasterModel.find_each do |master|
  master.increment!(:business_models_count, master.business_models.size)
end
```

And after that you will be able to get `business_models_count` of each `MasterModel` instance without N+1

```rb
MasterModel.limit(50).offset(0).each do |master|
  master.business_models_count
end
```